# How to get data correctly from graphql

Tags: node.js, mongodb, graphql, nestjs

I'm working on Nestjs project using graphql I want to display the objected nested in my response of graphql as you see below, so I have object comes from socket look like this

```
socket.emit('sendSettlement', {
        bReconcileError: true,
        batchNumber: 112233,
        btransfered: true,
        countryCode: 112233,
        currencyCode: 12233,
        merchantID: 'd2s13g',
        nSettlementAmount: 1122332,
        onlineMessageMACerror: true,
        reconciliationAdviceRRN: 1122333,
        reconciliationApprovalCode: '1122fdsf',
        settledTransactions: [
          {
            appName: '5411fdsb',
            cardInputMethod: '6s51b',
            cardPAN_PCI: '3f1dbs3df1sss',
            networkName: '5d4dsf',
            onlineApprovalCode: 11651,
            onlineRetrievalReferenceNumber: 6516161,
            transactionAmount: 156161,
            transactionDate: 'sd3f1g3',
            transactionTime: '2f4gB24G',
            transacttransactionTypeionTime: 'frqd56r1f',
          },
        ],

        settlementAmount: 'ds4f1vd1fv',
        settlementDate: '3dfv1',
        settlementTime: 'sd3f1vsdf',
        terminalID: 'sdRGRD',
        traceNumber: 12,
        uniqueID: 's56d1rvdr',
      });
```

I saved this to mongoDb correctly but when I want to get this data using graphql I got this Error

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Query.findAllSettlement.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "findAllSettlement"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}
```

and the console shows this

```
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("62aba86b614eef23deb46cfa"),
    bReconcileError: true,
    batchNumber: 112233,
    btransfered: true,
    countryCode: 112233,
    currencyCode: 12233,
    merchantID: 'd2s13g',
    nSettlementAmount: 1122332,
    onlineMessageMACerror: true,
    reconciliationAdviceRRN: 1122333,
    reconciliationApprovalCode: '1122fdsf',
    settledTransactions: [ [Object] ],
    settlementAmount: 'ds4f1vd1fv',
    settlementDate: '3dfv1',
    settlementTime: 'sd3f1vsdf',
    terminalID: 'sdRGRD',
    traceNumber: 12,
    uniqueID: 's56d1rvdr',
    __v: 0
  }
```

for who wants more info about my code : this is my Schema

```
export const SettlementSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  bReconcileError: { type: Boolean, required: false },
  batchNumber: { type: Number, required: false },
  btransfered: { type: Boolean, required: false },
  countryCode: { type: Number, required: false },
  currencyCode: { type: Number, required: false },
  merchantID: { type: String, required: false },
  nSettlementAmount: { type: Number, required: false },
  onlineMessageMACerror: { type: Boolean, required: false },
  reconciliationAdviceRRN: { type: Number, required: false },
  reconciliationApprovalCode: { type: String, required: false },
  settledTransactions: [
    {
      appName: String,
      cardInputMethod: String,
      cardPAN_PCI: String,
      networkName: String,
      onlineApprovalCode: Number,
      onlineRetrievalReferenceNumber: Number,
      transactionAmount: Number,
      transactionDate: String,
      transactionTime: String,
      transacttransactionTypeionTime: String,
    },
  ],
  settlementAmount: { type: String, required: false },
  settlementDate: { type: String, required: false },
  settlementTime: { type: String, required: false },
  terminalID: { type: String, required: false },
  traceNumber: { type: Number, required: false },
  uniqueID: { type: String, required: false },
});
```

this is my Object Type

```
@ObjectType()
export class SettledTransactionsType {
  @Field()
  appName: string;
  @Field()
  cardInputMethod: string;
  @Field()
  cardPAN_PCI: string;
  @Field()
  networkName: string;
  @Field()
  onlineApprovalCode: number;
  @Field()
  onlineRetrievalReferenceNumber: number;
  @Field()
  transactionAmount: number;
  @Field()
  transactionDate: string;
  @Field()
  transactionTime: string;
  @Field()
  transactionType: string;
}

@ObjectType()
export class Settlement {
  @Field()
  bReconcileError: boolean;
  @Field()
  batchNumber: number;
  @Field()
  btransfered: boolean;
  @Field()
  countryCode: number;
  @Field()
  currencyCode: number;
  @Field()
  merchantID: string;
  @Field()
  nSettlementAmount: number;
  @Field()
  onlineMessageMACerror: boolean;
  @Field()
  reconciliationAdviceRRN: number;
  @Field()
  reconciliationApprovalCode: string;
  @Field()
  settledTransactions: SettledTransactionsType;
  @Field()
  settlementAmount: string;
  @Field()
  settlementDate: string;
  @Field()
  settlementTime: string;
  @Field()
  terminalID: string;
  @Field()
  traceNumber: number;
  @Field()
  uniqueID: string;
}
```

Comment: Please include the code for the resolver too

Comment: @Query(() => [Settlement])
  findAllSettlement() {
    return this.settlementService.findAll();
  }

Comment: Are there other `settlements` in MongoDB that don't have all of these fields? To my understanding, all the fields are declared as non-null on your object type, but aren't `required` on the mongoose schema.